# React array state keeps resetting on update in functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-state, react-functional-component

I've created a React component with an array state `state.colors` that contains three hex values (initial state is `['#aaaaaa', '#aaaaaa', '#aaaaaa']`). Each value in the `state.colors` array can be updated using color pickers. As a test, I've updated the first color to red, second to green, and third to blue. This works as expected in a class component (as shown in the screenshot below).

```js
class EditArtworkClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      colors: initialPalette
    };
  }

  setColor(index, hex) {
    const clonedColors = _.clone(this.state.colors);
    clonedColors[index] = hex;

    this.setState(
      {
        colors: clonedColors
      },
      () => {
        console.log("updated");
      }
    );
  }

  // other code here
}
```

**Class Component - Before choosing colors:**

[image: Class component before updates]

**Class Component - After choosing colors (`state.colors` have the correct hex values):**

[image: Class component after updates]

However, I am facing an issue when using a functional component. Every time I update a color using the color picker, all other values in the `colors` state array are reset to the initial value (`#aaaaaa`). If I set the first color to red, second to blue, and third to green, only the last value in the `colors` array will have the correct hex since the other two values are reset to `#aaaaaa` when updating the third color.

```js
export default function EditArtworkFunctional() {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState(initialPalette);

  const setColor = (index, hex) => {
    const clonedColors = _.clone(colors);
    clonedColors[index] = hex;

    return clonedColors;
  };

  // Other code here
}
```

**Functional Component - Before choosing colors:**

[image: Functional component before updates]

**Functional Component - After choosing colors (only the last color I pick has a correct hex in the state):**

[image: Functional component after updates]

Note that the color picker is an uncontrolled component and will display the colors you pick, not the color in the `colors` state array.

I have created a reproducible mini-app in the [Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/class-vs-functional-component-array-state-8lnzd) below.

[image: App.js]

Condesandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/class-vs-functional-component-array-state-8lnzd

I have zero ideas as to why this is happening, so any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated .

**UPDATE**: I've fixed the problem using @TalOrlanczyk's answer. The trick was to retrieve the previous state using the optional parameter when updating. You can view the [CodeSandbox repo of the working version here](https://codesandbox.io/s/class-vs-functional-component-array-state-fixed-qdfeb).

Comment: Add your code to the question (only the relevant parts), or it will get useless when the link dies. **Tip:** You can add JS code snippets directly here in StackOverflow.

Comment: @emi I was concerned that the question would get too lengthy . But you're right -  I will edit the question to include relevant code in case the codesandbox link dies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I solve the problem

```
const setColor = (index, hex) => {
    setColors((prev) => {
      console.log(prev);
      const clonedColors = [...prev];
      clonedColors[index] = hex;
      return clonedColors;
    });
  };
```

like @theWellHopeErr says it cause because it happend because you didn;t send it as a spread operator
it's happend because array is reference if you change the same reference it's maybe change the value but the use state don't catch it because it's not a new reference.

Another thing you should know that is much better to use the like this (with the prev) because like that you can be sure you get the real last input you insert into this state

**UPDATE**

The spread operator is good only for shallow only when it's deep one like objects with a property with object this will not work and change the original state also.

[don't mutates the current state, this is an anti-pattern in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really)

this is a thread that explain it perfectly

**Clone array**
to do deep clone you should use

[a good artical in medium that explain about shallow and deep clone](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-deep-copy-objects-and-arrays-in-javascript-7c911359b089)

Comment: This seems to be the perfect solution I've been looking for. I wasn't even aware there was a way to retrieve the previous state in the lambda function when using `useState()`. Using your suggested fix worked like a charm.  Thank you @TalOrlanczyk!

Comment: thanks @subwaymatch look at the cloone array article I think it will help you alot

Answer (score 4):

This is because of two reasons

1. `const clonedColors = _.clone(colors)` using this deep clones the array which is not what we want, we have to make a shallow copy of the array . So, `const clonedColors = colors` will be the right way.
2. `setColors(clonedColors)` does not work correctly, but if we `setState` using spread syntax `setColors([...clonedColors])` it will. This is because the array is just a reference, and React `setState` won't rerender if the state doesn't get a new reference. That's why we send a new array reference by using the spread syntax `[...clonedColors]`. Thanks to @TalOrlanczyk for the reason.

```
const setColor = (index, color) => {
    const clonedColors = colors;
    clonedColors[index] = color;
    setColors([...clonedColors]);
    console.log(colors);
};
```

Here is the [Updated Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/class-vs-functional-component-array-state-forked-v1dkg)

Comment: it's happend because array is reference and setState will not rerender if the state don't get a new reference. so if we do a spread operator we get a new reference.

Comment: you know this is an anti pattern because you mutate the current state and this is anti pattern as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks both @theWellHopeErr and @TalOrlanczyk! Based on my understanding, I thought I always had to make a clone of the original state objects to treat them as immutable objects. I'm still a bit confused how using the spread operator is different from creating a clone with `_.clone()`. But I'll take time to read the docs and test them out. Again, thank you both!

Comment: _.clone() and spread operator are pretty much the same lodash
lodash solution for clone deep is ._cloneDeep()